# Creating post with ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Hello everyone i'm having some problems with ajax and actually i'm pretty new with jquery and ajax, i have my comment system in laravel, thanks to Stackoverflow community i can edit and update the comments via ajax, however i can create a new comment but with php method only and i'm trying to create new comments with ajax.

this is my view:

```
<article class="row">
```

```
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                          <div class="panel panel-default arrow left">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                              <header class="text-left">
                                <div class="comment-user"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ $comment->user->name }}</div>
                                <time class="comment-date" datetime="{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</time>
                              </header>
                              <div id="comment-post" data-commentid="{{ $comment->id }}">
                                  <p id="display-comment"{{ $comment->id }} class="store-comment">{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-footer list-inline comment-footer">
                              @if(Auth::guest())

                              No puedes responder ningún comentario si no has ingresado.

                              @else

                              @if(Auth::user() == $comment->user)
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="edit-comment" class="edit-comment">Editar</a> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="delete-comment" class="delete-comment">Eliminar</a>
                              @endif

                              @if(Auth::user() != $comment->user)
                                <a href="#">Responder</a>
                              @endif

                              @endif
                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </article>
```

here's my controller method store:

```
public function store(Request $request, $post_id)
{

  $post = Post::find($post_id);

  $this->validate($request, [
      'comment' => 'required'
  ]);

  $comment = new Comment();

  $comment->comment = $request['comment'];

  $comment->save();
  return response()->json(['edit_comment' => $comment->comment, $post->id, 'success' => true], 200);
```

}

Here's my ajax function:

```
    var urlCreate = '{{ url('comments/store') }}';


$('#create').submit(function(){
  var comentario = $('#add-comment').val();
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlCreate,
    data: {comentario: comment, _token: token, _method: 'PUT'},
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .done(function(message){
    if (message.success === true){
      $(divcomment).find('.store-comment').text(commentario);
    }
  });
});
```

I think this is useful, this is the ajax code that i'm using to update a comment "is working good".

```
var urlEdit = '{{ url('comments/update') }}';
    $('.edit-comment').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  divcomment = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  commentId = $("#comment-post", event.target.parentNode.parentNode).data('commentid');
  var commentBody = $(divcomment).find('#display-comment').text();
  $('#comment').val(commentBody);
  $('#edit-comment').modal();
});

$('#modal-save').on('click', function(){
    var $btn = $(this).button('loading');
    var comment = $('#comment').val();
    $(this).button('loading');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: urlEdit,
        data: {
            comment: comment,
            commentId: commentId,
            _token: token,
            _method: 'PUT',
         },
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function (msg){
        if (msg.success === true) {
            $(divcomment).find('#display-comment').text(comment);
        }
        $btn.button('reset');
        $('#edit-comment').modal('hide');
        success('Comentario editado.', '.alert .alert-success', {timeOut: 5000});
    });
});
```

My goal is to create a new comments without refreshing the whole page.

**UPDATE**

Token variable:

```
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
```

Comment: Where is your token variable in '_token: token,' getting assigned? Have you logged it's value to make sure it's valid?

Comment: @btl sorry for that, look at the code again, at the very bottom i added an update of my code

Comment: Are you getting any console error with your current code? You can remove the _token and just add the url in VerifyCsrfToken Middleware.

Comment: @Odinovsky actually i'm getting rightnow a laravel error but my code is wrong, is not executing the ajax, my controller method is wrong or my ajax is wrong

Answer (score 0):

All you need is using `serialize` method for data and it is not important to determine `dataType`

```
var urlCreate = '{{ url('comments/store') }}';
$('#create').submit(function(){
    var comentario = $('#add-comment').val();
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: urlCreate,
      data: $("#YourFormId").serialize(), 
      //dataType: 'json'
      success: function(){
         // show message and any logic
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, response){
         // In case of error use those params to produce informative message
      }
  })
```

Comment: so i have to delete the route in my form? `{{ Form::label('comment', ' Comentario', ['class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-comment pull-right label-space']) }}` that's how my form start. My controller is ok?

Comment: If I could understand you well, you have not to delete anything you have only able to see unique `id` attribute value in your `form` tag.

Comment: that id stores the new comment and relate that comment to the commented post, commend_id = 19 and post_id = 10, so that comment belongs to the post with id = 10

Comment: No, recall html form

Comment: So i need to crate a var who points to the form action right?

Comment: @JuanRincón Do you know HTML? If you have studied HTML well, you will, easily, know exactly and simply what I have meant.

Comment: i can call the form id but i should call it on the url? sorry i'm pretty new with js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146335/discussion-between-saidbakr-and-juan-rincon).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   var comment = $('#comment').val()
    , comment_id   = $('#comment-post').data('commentid')
 /* , post_id = $('#post_id').val() or {{ $post_id }} if you've passed it along */
   , urlEdit = '{{ url('comments/store') }}';

   $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:"urlEdit",
            data: {
                    comment: comment,
                    comment_id: comment_id
                },
            success:function(data){
                  /* reload element upon success */
            },
              error: function(data){
                 alert("Error Submitting Record!");
              }
       });
```

I'm not sure about your Controller. Why would you find Post?
If the Comment belongs to a certain post (i.e. your post_id), you may have to include the post_id var in the ajax above if the post_id is a foreign key to your comments table, then do it like so in the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
      'comment' => 'required'
  ]);
  $comment = new Comment();
  $comment->comment = $request->comment;
  $comment->comment_id = $request->comment_id;
  $comment->post_id = $request->post_id; // only if included
  $comment->save();
  return response()->json([ 'code'=>200], 200);
}
```

In the VerifyCsrfToken, place the post url:

```
protected $except = [
    '/comments/store'
];
```

Comment: this is the update function and is working `var comment = $('#comment').val()
 /* , post_id = $('#post_id').val() or {{ $post_id }} if you've passed it along */
   , urlEdit = '{{ url('comments/update') }}';

   $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:"urlEdit",
            data: {
                    comment: comment
                },
            success:function(data){
                  /* reload element upon success */
            },
              error: function(data){
                 alert("Error Submitting Record!");
              }
       });`

Comment: I just changed the url from above.

Comment: right but i realised that i need to get the post_id, look at my comment update ajax code and look the variable commentId = 0; then i call the comment id this way: `commentId = $("#comment-post", event.target.parentNode.parentNode).data('commentid')`

Comment: try getting it like so, comment_id   = $('#comment-post').data('commentid')...My answer above is updated.

Comment: i saw it but comment_id is calling the id of the comment that's not created, otherwise while updating a comment commentid is needed to get the correct comment to update it, in this case what i'm needing is the post_id, since the comment is visible in the post. @SaidbakR suggested that send the post_id in the form creating an hidden input field

Comment: right..if comment_id is the primary key and a serial in your table..it will be created automatically without even the need for having it in your script or the controller.just the post_id associated with it.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/juanr/Sites/devmedia/resources/views/news/single.blade.php) it sends the comment in a new window `{this is a new comment}` once back in the page and reloaded i get that error.. checking my database, the error is basically because the comment doesn't have an user_id "the user who post the comment" and is not defined the approved column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146339/discussion-between-odinovsky-and-juan-rincon).

Comment: never mind i added this `      $comment->approved  = true;
      $comment->user_id   =   auth()->id();` following the php method

Comment: lets go to chat

Comment: still having problems creating the new comment. it's redirecting me to the comments page with the comment @Daedalus